# Focus not exclusive to Modal Dialog in FF or Chrome when clicking on select list

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

When entering a value in Input Box then clicking on Select List (FF and Chrome), will get the focus on the select list not the Modal Dialog.

This does not happen in IE.

Any suggestions on how to prevent this behavior in FF and Chrome?

http://jsfiddle.net/r66tR/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a browser peculiarity but I came up with a solution (kludge really) for you:

```
<input id="blurrer" />

<select>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>    
</select>

<div id="dialog" style="display: none;">
    Hi there!
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
jQuery("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    close: function(event, ui) {
       jQuery("select").removeAttr("size");
    }
});


jQuery("#blurrer").blur(function() {
   jQuery("select").attr("size", "1");
   jQuery("#dialog").dialog("open");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r66tR/5/

Add, workaround that (sort of) works for Chrome:

http://jsfiddle.net/r66tR/7/

Comment: Thank for your assistance.  This does the trick in FF.  Chrome does not seem to acknowledge the modifications.  Maybe this is also a WebKit issue, Safari is behaving the same as Chrome.

Comment: @Joseph added a fiddle to my answer for Chrome. Really looks like browser craziness. The new fiddle prevents them from selecting anything but it still drops down.